# How to hide an element without taking up space and still respond to events?

Tags: javascript, html, css

`display:none` takes the element away from the layout flow and thus not taking up space on the page but its events get disabled.

`visibility:hidden` hides the element, but the element still takes up space.

I need a way to hide a file input element without taking up space and responding when I call its `.click()` event.

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/ahmoo/qxNC9/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply setting opacity to 0 should work. The element won't show up, and it wont take space either. And its events will work.

When giving opacity, also specify the opacity counterparts of all browsers (-moz.., -webkit, filter: ..) etc.. to ensure cross-browser compatibility.

**EDIT**

Your style should look something like:

```
.mydiv {
  position: absolute;
  left: 10px; /* change as needed */
  top: 10px; /* change as needed */
  opacity: 0;
}
```

Working demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/t2BHg/6/

Comment: I think thats exactly what these guys are doing. Setting opacity to 0. http://blueimp.github.com/jQuery-File-Upload/

Comment: I tried this but it didn't work. Although hidden, it still took up space. You can see [my example](http://jsfiddle.net/ahmoo/t2BHg/1/)

Comment: I forgot to mention, you will need to give position: absolute as well ! Sorry about that. :) I've updated my answer.

Comment: Have added a fiddle with a working demo of what you are looking for.

Answer (score 4):

How about making it invisible, but with absolute positioning off the left of the screen:

CSS:

```
#yourelement, .hidden {
   visibility : hidden;
   position   : absolute;
   left       : -1000px;
   width      : 1px;
   height     : 1px;
   overflow   : hidden;
}
```

Comment: I'm for this answer, although I would change left:-9999em, -1000px seems too little for +1280 res monitors..

Comment: @Nacho - Thanks, but I'm not sure how the resolution of the monitor matters. The point is to shift the element far enough to the left that its right-most point will still be off the _left_ edge of the screen. (Obviously the resolution would matter if trying to shift off the _right_ edge of the screen.)

Comment: that's exactly what I'm talking about, and -9999(em or px) won't harm

Comment: @nnnnnn - Your solution is a good one but it doesn't apply in my case. I have four `<input type="file">` elements that I want to hide from users. Each file input is grouped with a `<img>` (preview thumbnail) in a div, so I can't place the file input elements off the screen without affecting their corresponding preview thumbnail.

Comment: Sure you can. It doesn't matter now that you have a solution you're happy with, but as soon as you make it `position:absolute` (as in your accepted solution) it is as good as disconnected from the corresponding `<img>`. (Coordinates are still relative to containing element, but it is pulled from the normal document flow.)

Answer (score 4):

Setting `display: none;` does not disable events for an element, but it will prevent it from being clicked because the element has no pixel dimensions to click into.  You can still call its `onclick` events programmatically.  [See an example](http://jsfiddle.net/Vn9Fs/)

Comment: Appreciate the help. But what I am looking for is a way to trigger the "select file" dialog box of the file input element. Calling `.call()` on the element is the most straightforward solution that I can think of and thus the question. With your solution, I actually have to define how the element behaves for its `onclick`, but all I need is for it to behave normally - show the "select file" dialog.

Comment: I have added an example to my post.

Answer (score 2):

Less code:

```
position: fixed; z-index: -1;
```

Answer (score 1):

You could make it visibility: hidden and set width and height to 0

Comment: Not a perfect solution as it still takes up a tiny space ([see here](http://jsfiddle.net/ahmoo/nGAee/1/)). I'll give it a bit more time to see if there's a better answer. Otherwise, I'll go with your solution. Thx.